# Test PSU 8-Pin CPU/PCI-E Connection

Tags: power-supply

I've bought a second-hand Gigabyte P850GM PSU which I suspect might be faulty.

I have tested the 24-pin connector with a multi-meter and it is showing the correct voltages on the correct pins, however, I suspect that either incorrect EPS-12V cables have been supplied with the unit or that there is an issue with the 8-pin CPU/PCI-E outputs. When I plug in the 8-pin EPS-12V PSU -> CPU cable I am seeing the following voltages at the end of the cable:

[image: Voltages]

I also see these voltages when I check the connector directly on the PSU (which makes sense as each of the 8 wires runs straight from the PSU output pin to the connector).

Am I testing this incorrectly? Is this what you'd expect to see? Does it sound like a PSU and/or a cable issue?

Comment: The last pin pair is just to tell the device it can draw 150W rather than 75 - but idk what the voltage should show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The person I'd bought the PSU from must have included up the wrong cables.

I bought a replacement PSU-to-CPU cable for this specific model from AliExpress and one of the live 12v wires coming from the PSU was split into two, meaning that the CPU connector end saw 12v across each of the 4 pairs.